# NodeJS REST call with certificate. How could I know which file to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to open a connexion to an IBM Cognos TM1 server through NodeJS/Axios and to do so I need to pass, during the first REST API Call everything which is needed to authenticate :

- an username and password which I have
- certificate information as SSL is set to true (I don't want to ignore self signed certificates)

I've found [examples](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/284) on how to pass certificate information with Axios but at this time I didn't succeed in getting it to work :-(

I've put in a dedicated folder, the whole ssl folder a TM1 client software is using:

- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\applixca.pem
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\ibmtm1.arm
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\ibmtm1.crl
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\ibmtm1.kdb
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\ibmtm1.rdb
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\ibmtm1.sth
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\importsslcert.exe
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\tm1ca_v2.der
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\tm1ca_v2.pem
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\tm1store
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\uninstallSSL.bat
- E:\Development\nodejs\tm1query\assets\ssl\applixca.der

My problem is, which file do I need to use when creating the agent which will hold the connexion ?

Thanks in advance for helping or pointing me to information which can help me to go further in my understanding of how certificates works.

Regards,

Bob

Comment: How about using the `.pem` files and testing?

Comment: Hello Aritra, Testing with both `.pem`files return a `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`answer.